# CORS issues using Gravity Form API in Wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've been using gravity form APIs lately to get entries from a wordpress website to an angular app. The angular app is not deployed in the same domain as the wordpress website. Thus I'm having cors issues like **XMLHTTPRequest cannot load [...] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present.**

Has somewone ever faced this with Gravity Form APIs and have a solution for this CORS issue (like what to include ?) ?

Comment: @lin I tested your method and it worked. So I flagged it as the answer. But I ended deploying my external website in the same domain than the wordpress one and it's working without that new functions also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your CORS in wordpress by using the `init` action to bind a new WP-Function like:

```
add_action('init', 'handle_preflight');

function handle_preflight() {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept");

    if('OPTIONS' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        status_header(200);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your server to add the header
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`